# how to assign dynamically a color picker hex value as html attributes in php?

Tags: php, html

How do I create a color picker that the user can choose a desired hex value and dynamically place it as attributes in a html tag like in the example below.

```
<p style="background-color: #FCF8C0;">TEXT GOES HERE</p>
```

In the example code above, I want the `#FCF8C0` to be dynamic based on the user picking a color on the fly and once done choosing a hex value, the background dynamically changes on mouse out.

Comment: Thats a job for javascript, not php

Comment: @akatakritos I want it in PHP. and you can just say if its possible or not. why down vote?

Comment: I didnt downvote you, btw. But you can't handle the mouse out event in PHP. You can put a button that says "click to change color" which submits a form and re-renders the page in the new color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you CAN do it in PHP, but it would be more efficient to do in JS. For PHP, one way would be to refresh the page with a new $_GET value. Then you can use:

```
<?php echo("<p style='background-color:".$_GET['colorHex']."'>paragraph here</p>");?>
```

Provided that the URL is something like: `Test.com/page.php?colorHex=#094037`

Comment: thanks for your answer. and I just dont know why people loved to downvote a newbie question. if I knew it, I dont bother asking it. and someday when a newbie saw this post, he/she will know that its not possible so this question can be helpful for newbies like me.

Comment: No problem, I understand. We were all newbies once in our lifetime. If you think this answer had been helpful, please select it as the accepted answer (the checkmark), it will help other users who view this question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do it with PHP, you use JavaScript for things like that.
PHP is a Server-Sided language, You want to do something that occures on the Client-Side and therefore you should use JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I dont know as Im a beginner that's why Im asking a question.